# Drupal $_SESSION issue (value not being retained)

Tags: drupal, session

I have 2 php files that are being used to set and retrieve a very specific session variable.

The initial script sets the value like:

```
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';    
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);

if(($_POST['region'])){
    $_SESSION['region'] = $_POST['region'];
    print '1';  
}else{
    print '0';
}
```

and the other page that retrieves the value looks like:

```
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';    
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);

if(isset($_SESSION['region'])){
    print '1';  
}else{
    print '0';
}
```

My issue is that the script that needs to retrieve the value (in a seperate external page, as is the one that sets it) always sees the $_SESSION array as being empty.

I've updated my $base_url just incase.. and I've also printed out the session_id() and manually gone to each external page to ensure they match, and they do.

I'm at a loss as to what to do at this point?

Any takers?

Comment: does it work if you call session_start yourself?

Comment: No, that didn't make a difference.

Comment: It's very weird.. sometimes when I do the post to set the session and then retrieve it's value.. it works, but never right away. It can take up to 4-5 attempts in order to get the value back from the session.

Comment: I've also had it so that the page that sets the session value, returns the value from the session itself and it always returns successfully. It's only the page that is setup to retrieve the session value that seems to never see the session array as having the new value in it. Unless of course I repeatedly hit the button and then the 4-5th try seems to work.

Comment: The 4-5 is also sporadic. Sometimes it happens after 2, or 8 tries.. so it can't be a time delay of some sort. Really odd.

Comment: To add to the issue, firefox and chrome appear to be fine. IE seems to be flaky and unreliable in this regard. Does this make sense to anyone with drupal experience? I can't see why the browser would make a different when it comes to a scripting language?

Comment: As another side note, I'm also fetching the output of these scripts using ajax. However I am making a POST to help get around the fact that IE caches GET requests unless adding on the random time stamp etc.

Comment: Do you have multiple web servers handling this site? @Orbit: you shouldn't require `session_start` as Drupal bootstrapping should do that.

Comment: no, it's a single server handling all requests for this site.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the added comments.